# HornetQ JBoss and Weblogic message Transaction

Tags: jboss, weblogic, hornetq

We have two applications which is running on Weblogic and JBoss AS respectively. We would like to Keep HornetQ as an intermediate server for Asynchronous messaging.

I would like to write a Publish/Subscriber. Whenever a data Inserted/Modified/Deleted(JPA) or whatever possible messages it could be.

Here Producer will be the Weblogic and consumer will be the JBOSS. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

On wls end define a foreign jms server.  Point it to the hornetq topic. Your application on wls will publish 
Messages to foreign jms and your application on jboss can consume it.

When defining foreign jms make sure you provide user credentials for both the topic and jndi look up as needed.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. In HornetQ i would like to invoke all the consumers(Whomever registered with...) business Logic whenever i get notifications from WLS.

Answer (score 0):

I think You could use JMS bridge between wls and JBoss:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.CR2/docs/user-manual/html/jms-bridge.html